# How to modify the configuration of Payara running in Docker when a restart is needed

Tags: docker, glassfish, payara

I'm using the Payara image in Dockerhub. If I want to change a configuration parameter in Payara that requires a restart (via asadmin restart domain) the container stops.

How can you make configuration changes like the above without the container stopping ?

I've raised an issue for this:

https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/issues/45

Answer (score 1):

In Docker, containers should be preconfigured in the DockerFile and when you change the configuration, you should rebuild your docker container and restart it. You shouldn't expect that you change the config dynamically without a restart, that's not how most of the Docker containers work.

You still can do what you want with the current Payara docker image if you overwrite the ENTRYPOINT using `bin/asadmin start-domain` instead of the `startInForeground.sh` script. This will execute a launcher Java process, which will watch over the server process and restart it when needed. The `startInForeground.sh` script is used by default to optimize running the server in the container.